# Check whether a long is randomly generatable by Random.nextLong()

Tags: java

As you may know, `Random.nextLong()` does not generate all possible long values in Java. How can I check if a specific long is randomly generatable by that method?

Comment: Why do you want to know that? That sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the JavaDoc to Random says:

> The implementation of {@code setSeed} by class {@code Random}
> happens to use only 48 bits of the given seed. In general, however,
> an overriding method may use all 64 bits of the {@code long}
> argument as a seed value.

But you may also want to check out [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) since it does not appear to have the 48 bit seed limit.  And it is also faster.